# I Cannot Play Any Videos On My Mac Computer Using Multiple Browsers

Tags: mac, safari, video, web-browser, adobe-flash

Until a few weeks ago I was able to play videos on Facebook, YouTube and many other websites on my Mac Mini Server (mid-2011) running High Sierra. Now when I attempt to play videos they either just sit there or show a progress bar. They never play. This happens on all the browsers I have installed: Safari, Chrome, Firefox and Opera.

I have the latest versions of all of them installed. I have cleaned the cache of all of them. I have turned off hardware acceleration as suggested on some blogs. I have the latest versions of Flash (NPAPI, PPAPI) installed.

I don't have this problem on my MacBook Air (mid 2011). The only web blocking I have turned on using Sophus is for websites known to have malware. I run no antivirus software. At this point I assume there is an OS setting somewhere on my Mac Mini Server that I need to change to get this working again.

UPDATE December 5, 2018: This morning I started using Facebook, YouTube, etc. and had no problems playing videos. I checked on Opera and Safari, the two browsers I use regularly. I did nothing else other than what I stated in this question. I have no idea what happened other than it was unique to my Mac Mini Server.

Comment: I get that sometimes on Mojave, not only on browsers but also on VLC; a soft reboot usually fixes it.

Comment: what is your Playback setting in Adobe Flash

Comment: @Buscar웃 on both of my computers 'Ask me when a site wants to use peer-assisted networking' is set in Flash Player System Settings. The screen says the settings on that page are not applicable to Google Chrome or Chromium based browsers. Opera uses PPAPI.

Comment: @Tetsujin, I rebooted my computer but I still have the problem.

Comment: Having the same issue, did you manage to solve this problem? @PamelaCook-LightBeCorp

Comment: @Ritesh, videos started playing without me doing anything. I don't remember if there were any OS updates at the time. I have not had that problem again.

Comment: @PamelaCook-LightBeCorp Same with me. Problem gone after system update.

Comment: @ritesh I bumped in to the exact same problem with one of my three computers. No videos play anywhere, not in any browsers (tested with private windows), not in VLC, not in Quicktime. I conclude that something on the OS level is "stuck" but what? I guess it is GPU (driver) related. Would be interesting to find the culprit. I have tried killing processes with name such as video, GPU, Quicktime, so far to no avail. Voted to reopen the question. More people should do that.

Comment: @d-b This question is about a 2011 Mini, High Sierra and Flash, all of which are rather dated nowadays (or simply not available anymore), also the problem resolved itself so no further analysis for the specific HW/SW configuration was possible. If you have a similar issue on your Macs, please post a new question describing your environment etc.

Comment: @nohillside It is not about Flash. Youtube started migrating from Flash to HTML5 2011 and Chrome started to force HTML5 2014 (https://www.skipser.com/p/2/p/default-to-flash-player-youtube-in-chrome.html) and YT changed the default 2015 https://venturebeat.com/media/youtube-ditches-flash-for-html5-video-by-default/ . I am pretty sure this question, asked 4 years ago, had nothing to do with Flash, even though it is mentioned in the question.

Comment: @d-b We have been there before. The question is five years old, refers to old hardware and software and the OP has solved the problem. If you have a similar problem, please post a new question including the details relevant for your setup.

Comment: @d-b I agree - this needs to be a new question. If a specific macOS update is what resolved the issue here, it's obviously not going to be the solution for you (unless you're running an old OS version pre the update in question, in which case you would just ensure all updates are installed). Apart from that, posting a new question is your best bet here.